# php reuse curl_setopt's from previous request?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to set multiple `curl_setopt` only once and re-use them in future curl exec's as long as the curl handle is not closed ? (Especially Useragent and the Cookie)

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PHPSESSID=".session_id());
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://foo.bar/action/");
$ret = curl_exec($curl);

## DO SOME STUFF ##    

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://foo.bar/anotherAction/"); // Set only new URL ..
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // ... and the POST data.
$ret2 = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: this is a yes or no answer, I think you need to change your question for good answers

Comment: one more thing what did you try?

Comment: - changed topic -
currently I define Useragent and the Cookie in every request - that's why I'm asking if it is possible to NOT re-set them in every request. if so, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is as simple as the question .. just do it the way I did in the question. As long as the cURL session is not closed by `curl_close();`, you can query as many requests as you like with the headers of your choice only set once after `curl_init();`.